# Elantech touchpad do not works on all Ubuntu flavors

Tags: xubuntu, touchpad, lenovo, mate, elantech

I have a Lenovo IdeaPad 315 laptop with a Elantech touchpad, I made a "research" and this touchpad works only on Ubuntu 16.04/17.10  and on Ubuntu Mate 16.04 (I not tested on Ubuntu Mate 17.10, but I think that will work). I tested it on OpenSUSE Leap and on all others Ubuntu's flavors and not works on any of these.

Where I can found the difference between Ubuntu/Ubuntu Mate and others flavors?
I'm running Ubuntu 17.10 right now but I want install Xubuntu.

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try Ubuntu 14.04 as well?  My guess is that you are testing it on Supported Versions of Ubuntu that should work.  Ubuntu 17.04 is no longer supported so there is a chance that it won't install on it.

Comment: And the differences are mostly regarding the default desktop environment that's different and it may handle input devices differently.

Comment: @Terrance all flavors where I tested were LTS.

Comment: @MichaelBay then the Gnome based enviroments works well with my touchpad?

Comment: @ChristianM If you say so... My comment was just to let you know that you may be onto something, i.e., it's indeed plausible different flavours giving different results when handling input devices.

Comment: @MichaelBay yes, Now I think that the Gnome based environments works well with my touchpad, I will test it with others distros with Gnome.